# ipython doesn't work in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython

Why doesn't ipython find the tensorflow package, as below?

```
(tensorflow) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ which ipython
~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/ipython
(tensorflow) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

But if I explicitly executes bin/ipython, it works, as below:

```
(tensorflow) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ envs/tensorflow/bin/ipython
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]:
```

There is no problem with that. What's the reason?

Comment: you need to `pip install ipython`

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3321